# SSIS - cast a date to use in an expression

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I want to cast a date into ISO format, and use it as a string in an expression in SSIS.

This is what I type in T-SQL

```
select convert(varchar(8), GetDate(), 112)
```

and this is what I get back

```
20100630
```

My goal - is to create an archive folder based on the date. I have the File System Task part of creating a folder sorted, I can do that ... I just need to be able to Cast the date to a string, so I can use that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add an expression:

```
RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 4) DATEPART("yyyy", GetDate()), 4) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DatePart("mm", GetDate()), 2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DatePart("dd", GetDate()), 2)
```

This expression will create the result that you are after.

Comment: ALMOST correct. that returned 100630, but I changed the ,2 to a ,4 on the first line, and got 20100630, which is exactly what I wanted. So you get a hearty pat on the back, and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, better-er answer, from Adrian's comment [here](http://phil-austin.blogspot.co.nz/2008/01/ssis-expression-for-yyyymmdd-iso-date.html):

> Try an intermediate cast to type DT_DBDATE. Casting to WSTR gives a
>   string in format "YYYY-MM-DD", which is easily tidied up:
>
> REPLACE((DT_WSTR,200)(DT_DBDATE)GETUTCDATE(),"-","")

Or use without the `REPLACE` to get the `YY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 2):

In SSIS you would use the DT_STR or DT_WSTR cast to accomplish. A few examples are

```
(DT_STR, 4, 1252)YEAR(GETDATE()) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)MONTH(GETDATE()), 2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DAY(GETDATE()), 2)
```

or

```
(DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)MONTH(GETDATE()),2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DAY(GETDATE()), 2)
```

See the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, here is a reference guide I use frequently:

http://sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Expression-Date-Functions.aspx